# Bounded level sets of multivariate polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $p:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a multivariate polynomial. Suppose that $p$ is bounded below, that is, $p(x)>c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For any fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ let

$$S_{p(x_0)}=\{x|~~p(x)\leq p(x_0)\}$$

be a level set of $p$. Show that $S_{p(x_0)}$ is bounded for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My intuition is that if any entry of $x$ goes to infinity, then $p$ goes to infinity. Hence, it is not possible that a level set extends to infinity in any direction, which implies boundedness. Am I right? Also, is the hypothesis that $p(x)>c$ for all $x$ even needed ?

EDIT: A counter-example was provided in the answer. Follow-up question: what are the (least restrictive) additional assumptions on $p$ such that the level sets are bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(xy-1)^2$.

Then $f$ is strictly bounded below by $c=-1$, but the level set at the point $(1,1)$ is unbounded.

Even simpler: Let $f(x,y)=x^2$. Then again we can use $c=-1$, and we can take the level set at any point of $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, the level set at the point $(0,0)$ is the $y$-axis.

The above examples show that the claim of the original question is false.

As regards your updated question, as stated, it's too vague.

**My suggestion:**

Investigate lots of examples and see if you can determine what you think is  an appropriate condition, and then if you're not sure, post it as a *new* question.

Comment: Thank you. Let us exclude your simpler example and assume that all variables appear explicitly in the polynomial. What additional properties do I need for boundedness? For example, if we consider $f(x,y)=(xy-1)^2+\epsilon_1 x^2 +\epsilon_2 y^2$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon_1>0$, $\epsilon_2>0$ then the boundedness property should hold...

Comment: Let $f=(x-y)^2 = x^2-2xy+y^2$, and consider the level set at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Right, so explicit appearance of monomials in one variable is not sufficient. We could shift again $(x^2-y^2)^2+\epsilon_1x^2+\epsilon_2y^2$ and get bounded level sets. I'm wondering if there are smarter sufficient conditions.